# Multiset Notation

Tags: notation, multisets

There is a multiset $A$, of length $n$ that can contain only $1s$ or $0s$. How would I notate that? How about for a multiset that could contain any number from $1-1000$, or that could contain any real number?

Comment: What exactly is a *binary* multiset? Googling "binary multiset" turns up nothing relevant.

Comment: @Rahul edited. thanks for the comment.

Comment: I'd just stick to plain old English.

Comment: $A \in \mathbb{N}^{\{0,1\}}, A(0) + A(1) = \|A\|_1 = n$. $A \in \mathbb{N}^{[1,1000]}$. $A \in \mathbb{N}^\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A multiset of length $n$ that contains only $0$s and $1$s can be described as a multiset of cardinality $n$ whose underlying set is a subset of $\{0,1\}$. If you need to be formal, this is an ordered pair $\langle S,m \rangle$ such that $S \subseteq \{0,1\}$, $m:S \to \mathbb{Z}^+$, and $\sum\limits_{s \in S}m(s) = n$. Here $S$ is the underlying set, and $m$ is the multiplicity function. You can of course replace $\{0,1\}$ by any other set: $\{n \in \mathbb{Z}:1 \le n \le 1000\}$, $\mathbb{R}$, or whatever.

Comment: Sounds complex.

Comment: Why not get rid of the $S$ and just keep $m : \{0,1\} \to \mathbb N$, where $\mathbb N$ includes $0$?

Comment: @Rahul: It’s largely a matter of convention: most authors (in my experience) disallow $0$ as a multiplicity. There are some notable exceptions, however: Richard P. Stanley does exactly what you suggest in his *Enumerative Combinatorics*.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I'm uninformed on this stuff so pardon the simple question, but $S\subseteq \{0,1\}$ means $S=\{1\}$ is possible? But that would rule out any 0's in the multiset? I guess the question(s) is: Can $S$ here be a set with one element. If so, does that just indicate we have a multiset consisting of one element repeated $n$ times?

Comment: @user106860: Very belatedly — I wasn’t around when you asked — the answer is *yes*: $S=\{1\}$ is possible. In that case $m(1)=n$ (assuming that the multiset is of length $n$).